# Reseting all variables between each input during a DoE for a multi-disciplinary analysis

Tags: python, openmdao

I am working on a code developped with WhatsOpt (a web application allowing to define and share multi-disciplinary analyses in terms of disciplines and data exchange https://whatsopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ). And I have a problem.

**Context** : This code has to calculate different masses of an aircraft for a given climb acceleration. When I try to make a DoE, there are some climb accelerations that cause the masses to diverge. But this is not an issue because when the solver reaches the maximum iteration number, it tells it did not converge, and I simply don't keep the result.

**Problem** : In a DoE when you run the analysis for the input number n, the inner variables and responses are initialized with the values at the end of analysis n-1 (the previous one). So if the analysis with the input number n-1 diverged and set the variables to ridiculously high values, the analysis number n could not converge in the given number of iteration, whereas it should.

I tried to set a function which resets the masses to 1 when they reached a critical value, but this led to converge cases which should diverge. And then I can't drop the irrelevent results.
I tried to increase the maximum number of iterations for the solver, but it led to have even bigger values for diverging cases so, the good ones still did not converge

**Question** : Do you know how I could reset the values of all variables between each new input during the DoE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the feature you want to use a `guess_nonlinear` method either at a group level or a component level (model dependent).

Here are the openMDAO docs for [`guess_nonlinear`](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.9.1/features/core_features/grouping_components/guess_method.html?highlight=guess_nonlinear), which lets you set initial values for whatever you like at the start of any solver iterations.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you very much !